# how i can see if an array with arguments is null in c

Tags: c, arrays, null, strcmp

i have this code :

```
  int main(int re, char *args[]){
  int comp=1;
  int j=2;
  int count=0;
 //printf("%d",args[1]);
  while(comp!=0){
       comp=strcmp(args[j],"null");
       j++;
       count++;
  }
}
```

and i want to see how many string i have in my argument array (args[]), the problem is that a take segmentation fault and i cant find why.
When i put NULL instead "null" i get the same result ,segmentation fault.
There is a problem with args[j]? or is something else that i dont see?
Iam getting out of bounce in my array?
i know that the strings begin from args[2] so this is why i put j=2 in the code
i put the header file #include  to use strcmp

Comment: Why are you renaming `argc` to `re`? Also, to check if a pointer is null, use `if (myPointer == NULL) {...}`. And while I'm at it, your `while` loop logic will take you past any eventual arguments, since you only go up and don't stop till you hit 0.

Comment: `re` is the size of `args`, so use that to check if you've gone out of bounds

Comment: Note that `"null"` is a constant char array containing 5 characters : `'n' 'u' 'l' 'l' '\0'`, and `NULL` is a constant defined in `stdlib.h`. `"null" == NULL` will always be `false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"null"` is a string literal with no special meaning, and `NULL` is a null-pointer (you could just as well write `0` for it), which is what you mean, but comparing it as a string (with `strcmp()`) doesn't make **any** sense. You want to know whether the *pointer* at `args[j]` is null (and then, it isn't pointing to anything, so it isn't a string).

Although you get passed the number of arguments in the *first* parameter to `main()` anyways, which is almost always simpler to use, the C standard guarantees you that `argv[argc]` is indeed `NULL`, so your approach works when implemented correctly. Example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (argv[i])  // or more explicit while (argv[i] != NULL)
    {
        puts(argv[i++]); // print this argument
    }
}
```

Relevant passage in the standard (citing N1570 here) is **§5.1.2.2.1 p2**:

> [...]
>   -- `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The main function has two parameters,

```
int main(int argc, char **argv);
```

`argc` counts the number of arguments

`argv` has the arguments as strings in a 2D array.

So, You can just say:

```
if (argc == 1)
{
   printf("I'm having 0 arguments in Total");
}
```

The first argc takes up the name of the executable - `a.out`- . So, if you didn't change the name, a.out is the first argument.

Comment: You might add that the first entry is the name of the program

Comment: `argc` will always be at least 1 because `argv[0]` should contain the name of the executable

Comment: @ChrisTurner is this guaranteed? The C standard only tells `argc` is *non-negative*. I guess you can provoke `argc == 0` on a POSIX system with `execv()`.

Comment: @ChrisTurner `argc` is not specified to be at least 1.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Correct me if I'm wrong, but to check the number of arguments, we have to execute the program. Therefore, argc will always be 1 right?

Comment: @joemartin94 C spec also has "If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]`
represents the program name; ..."

Comment: @joemartin94 *executing the program* isn't automatically the same as passing an argument.